# Add Word Embedding in Neo4j

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

Trying to add word embedding to my nodes using Unwind.

The code:

```py
result = conn.query("MATCH (m:Word) WHERE NOT exists(m.embedding) RETURN m")
nodes = [x['m'] for x in result]
        for dic in nodes:
            dic['embedding'] = list(np.round(model_st.encode(dic['name'], show_progress_bar=False), 3))
query_update = f""" UNWIND $nodes as res_dict
                    MATCH (n:Word {{name: res_dict.name}})
                    SET n.embedding = res_dict.embedding
                """
self.conn.query(query=query_update, parameters={'nodes': nodes})
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Parameters of type float32 are not supported
```

How can I achieve it in Python?
Is there a better way to set an embedding to a node?

Comment: Only 64-bit integers and floating-point numbers are supported by Neo4j drivers.

Comment: @fbiville Thanks, so what we will be right way to create embedding?

Comment: not sure what "np.round" is, but you should make sure it returns a 64-bit float instead of a 32-bit one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add embedding using the following code

```
embedding = list(np.round(model_st.encode(name, show_progress_bar=False).astype(np.float64),3))
```

I still think it's weird neo4j don't have a native way to create embedding (using apoc/gds)